# How to store an array of objects in redis with node redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to store an array of objects as shown in redis:

```js
const obj_arr = [
{
id: 20,
name: 'bob'
},
{
id: 31,
name: 'greg'
}
]
```

How would I store this array in node redis and push and pop from it?

Comment: you can sore your data based on three type in redis : string, List(array), Hash(object), do you want to store data based on List ?https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro